# How to switch image on click by change border in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a select-unselect image by change border color on click by [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/mzySD/3/)

```
var $box=null;

$('img')
    .click(function() {
        if ($box == null) {
            $box = $(this);
            $box.css("border","5px solid green");
        } else  {
            $box.css("border","5px solid white");
            $box = null;
        }
    }
);
```

The code is working fine except when I try to select-unselect and select same image. I want to select the other image by one click.

I tried to check `if ($box == $(this))` but it does not work.

Comment: Is it important to store the selected state (for use in other parts of your code) or do you just want to toggle the style of the border?

Comment: Yes, I need to store null state(no one selected) for other control

Comment: Ok, and are you saying that in a set of images, only 1 can be selected?

Comment: Yes, only-one or No-one(select then de-selected) selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a class instead, and toggle the class when needed. This solution acts like a radio button (only one image with a border at a time), but allows you to deselect the active image as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/6cGVz/

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice Thanks! if ($this.hasClass('active')) also useful for ther control

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

Check if `$box` is the clicked element or not. If it is, just hide its border if it has one. Otherwise, put the border on the clicked element!

---

### Solution ([Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/mzySD/4/))

#### JavaScript/JQuery

```
var $box=null;

$('img')
    .click(function() {
        if ($box == null) {
            $box = $(this);
            $box.css("border","5px solid green");
        } else  {
            $box.css("border","5px solid white");
            if($box != $(this))
            {
                $box = $(this);
                $box.css("border","5px solid green");
            }
            else
                $box = null;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update - only one image can be selected**

[toggleClass of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method make it so easy -

Using Js -

```
$('img').click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $("img.selected").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        $("img.selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }

});
```

with css -

```
.selected{
    border:5px solid green;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/moazzam_khan/mzySD/9/)

Comment: Doesn't fully meet the requirements

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of your question, I will put all of the images in a container:

```
<div id='setOfImages'>
    <img ... >
    <img ... >
    <img ... >
    <img ... >
</div>
```

Toggle a class.

```
$('#setOfImages > img').click(function() {
    'use strict';

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        // Deselect currently selected image
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        // Deselect others and select this one
        $('#setOfImages > img').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

And in your CSS:

```css
#setOfImages > img {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
}

#setOfImages > img.selected {
    border: 5px solid green;
}
```

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79fTD/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data attribute to the image itself, instead of relying on something external.

```
$('img')
    .click(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        if (! img.data('box')) {
            img.css("border","5px solid green");
            img.data('box', true);
        } else  {
            img.css("border","5px solid white");
            img.data('box', false);
        }
    }
);
```

A working example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/qbztj

Comment: Doesn't fully meet the requirements